# Complex GQL Query

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

GQL has support for operations like `count` or `unique`.

I want to create a dashboard with some statistics for my application. And I want to create an object to store theses statistics.

Once a day, shoud execcute a query with something like that:

```
SELECT count(user_id), count(distinct(item_id)), ... FROM Object WHERE ts > one_day_ago
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute operations like count or unique. You have to handle by programing language